# is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?

Tags: c

Keep receiving an error code when trying to update 2D array with a data member. This 2D array has 5 elements to represent 5 hills on an island and each hill has a height slope and name etc. initialized the array main to be default all 0 and none for the name using my function but now need to update the array and data member with info that is given so no need for user input. Have looked at posts about this error code but cannot solve in this instance. Also tried to update other data first like hillArray.loc[0] thinking maybe its the strcpy but nope its the way updating the array is the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Hill {
  char name[20];
  int loc[2];
  double height;
  double slope;
  } Hill;

Hill* setHill (struct Hill* hill){
 strcpy(hill->name,"none");
 hill->loc[0] = 0;
 hill->loc[1] = 0;
 hill->height = 0;
 hill->slope = 0;
return hill;
}

int main() {
  struct Hill* hillsArray[5];
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    setHill(hillsArray[i]);
}

strcpy((hillsArray->name[0]), "Ada's Apex");  // error is here, trying to update hillsArray  

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790701/struct-hill-hillsarray-is-a-pointer-did-you-mean-to-use (Same homework, different students).

Answer (score 1):

Your `hillsArray->name[0]` subscripts the wrong identifier.

`hillsArray` identifies an *array* of pointers.  You must apply the subscript there to choose the specific one of them that points to the `Hill` you want to access:

```
strcpy(hillsArray[0]->name, "Ada's Apex");
```